# refering to already existing group in regex, c#

Tags: c#, regex, shrink

I have a regex where

```
%word% can occur multiple times, separated by a "<"
```

%word% is defined as `".*?"|[a-zA-Z]+`
so i wrote

```
(".*"|[a-zA-Z]+)([<](".*"|[a-zA-Z]+))*
```

Is there any way i can shrink it using capturing groups?

```
(".*"|[a-zA-Z]+)([<]\1)*,
```

But i don't think `\1` can be used as it'd mean repeat the first capture, as i would not know what was captured as it can be a quoted string or a word.

Any thing similar i can use to refer matching the previously written group. I'm working in C#.

Comment: with grep it works, interesting question:) +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the support is not there yet for the feature, i made a string replacer, where i wrote the specific words i need to replaced by regex using %% and then wrote the program to replace it by the regular expression defined for the text.

Answer (score 1):

using String.Format to avoid repetition and no there is no way to repeat the regex group literally

```
String.Format("{0}([<]{0})*", @"("".*""|[a-zA-Z]+)")
```