# regex: matching same expression unknown number of times

Tags: .net, regex

With the help of some of the guys here I have some regex to match strings in quotes that aren't in brackets:

```
"one" - matches
("two") - doesn't match
```

Is it possible to repeat the match so the input:

```
"one" ("two") "three"
```

would return one and three? The only thing I can think of doing is capturing whatever is left over and reprocessing with the same regex, i.e:

```
process > "one" ("two") "three" - returns one and "("two") "three""
process > ("two") "three"       - returns failed and "three", not sure how but hey
process > "three"
```

I'm learning regex at the moment so just wondering if this functionality is built in?

NB: this may be a repeat of [refering to already existing group in regex, c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638113/refering-to-already-existing-group-in-regex-c) but not clearly enough for me to follow :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [`Regex.Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) function which returns all of the substrings that match the regex.